# Rails 3 trying to load files in fixtures/files folder as fixtures

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, testing

I'm using fixture_file_upload in some of my tests and the files are in fixtures/files.

However, whenever I try to run my tests, it appears that Rails is trying to load those files as if they were fixtures and I end up getting errors like this:

```
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: Mysql::Error: Table 'testapp_test.test_image' doesn't exist: DELETE FROM `test_image`
```

From what I've gathered (and in my experience with previous versions of Rails), it should only be loading the yml files in the root of the fixtures directory but it's loading everything instead.

Comment: Have you found out anything about this since you created the question?  I ran into this today.  Annoying.

Answer (score 1):

Adding support for namespaced fixtures left fixture_file_upload semi-broken. Here's the commit:

https://github.com/rails/rails/commit/8ec085bf1804770a547894967fcdee24087fda87

It should only get in the way for CSV or YML files, but that's not much help. But since fixture_file_upload is now just a shortcut for Rack::Test::UploadedFile.new(ActionController::TestCase.fixture_path + path, type), that leads to the solution.

Moving 'files' out from under 'fixtures' and calling Rack::Test::UploadedFile.new directly worked for me.